# Detect navigation changes in iOS on a global level

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Is there a way to detect a navigation change in iOS on a global level, either in AppDelegate or SceneDelegate? So basically, any present, push or dismiss that triggers a delegate or a notification? I know android has a method for this particular use case and there's also a useFocusEffect in React Native but I can't find anything similar in iOS. Went through the list of all NSNotifications and couldn't find anything, except for one that is linked to MacOS only.

Comment: No, each navigation controller is responsible for their own stack.

Comment: I think Method swizzling helps you. try to search Method swizzling viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need this, but you could make an extension of `UINavigationController` and implement the Delegate on itself, then assign the delegate in `viewDidLoad`. This is very hacky but would look like this:

```
extension UINavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
    
    public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // Do code here
    }
    
}
```

Would you mind sharing why you need this though? as there might be a more iOS standard way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm building an analytics tracker for few company apps, and i need an elegant way to log which controller the user is at the moment with as little as possible intervention from the other dev teams. I'm aware I could implement a custom event which the dev can call from each controller, but the existing app has 50+ views meaning 50+ changes

Comment: + this would only work for controllers that are part of navigation stack. If the controller is presented as a modal this wouldn't work

Comment: With UINavigationController extension you can override `pushViewController` and `presentViewController` you could use this same implementation on a `UIViewController`